# PHP variable name in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$resultSystem = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM templates where templateId = 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultSystem))
{
$Part1 = $row["Part1"];
}

$name = "Peter";
echo $Part1;
```

In my database $Part1 results in $name.
I would like the code to print the name "Peter", however it prints $name.
How do I make PHP print the value of the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `$Part1 = 'name';`

```
$name ="Peter";
```

Then

```
echo $$Part1 will print "Peter"
```

Comment: I prefer for clarity ${$Part1}

Comment: woah, I've never thought this kind of thing was possible :o... yep... over 6 years of programming, and I didn't know this small trick... -.-

Answer (score 0):

Use function `eval()` like

```
eval("echo $Part1");
```

However, be very careful so the users don't launch malicious code.